# Pop up html page as a jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have a properties page `foo-properties.html` in full html (i.e., the root element is <html> ). I don't want to convert it to be div-wrapped. I want to show the properties page as a jQuery UI dialog, is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, can you put it into an iframe and use the frame's wrapper as the modal overlay?